# How to assign value of a stored procedure to a variable in snowflake

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have 2 procedures. the first one is being called inside the second after some condition. simplified code below. Would like to know how to call a proc and assign the output to a variable that i can use in Snowflake

```
create procedure first_proc(table1 varchar)
return varchar
language sql 
as 
declare
 val int;
begin
select row into val from employees;
if (val = 0) then
return ‘yes’;
else
return ‘NO’;
end if ;
end;
```

***second procedure***

```
create procedure second_proc()
return varchar
language sql 
as 
declare
script varchar;
begin
create table schoolTable (schooldt datetime)
script := call first_proc(table1)
if script = ‘yes’    -- me referring to the return from the first procedure 
then insert in schoolTable value (‘some value’)
else
return (‘message’)
end if;
end;
```

I am getting an error it says: sql compilation error: error line 1 invalid identifier ‘table 1’

Comment: From the documentation https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/result_scan.html#:~:text=use%20RESULT_SCAN%20to%20process%20the%20value%20returned%20by%20a%20stored%20procedure

Comment: You don't appear to have assigned table1 to anything before you use it in the call to first_proc

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work. However, I don't understand why you would create the table schoolTable inside the second stored procedure. The second time you run the stored procedure, you would get an error because the table already exists. So I have removed the create table statement from the second procedure. The table `schoolTable` that you are creating has one column with data type datetime, but you are inserting a character string 'some value', this would also fail so I have replaced 'some value' with current_timestamp. Also, I don't understand what you are trying to do in the first procedure, because `select row into val from employees;` will fail if the table employees contains more than one record. When you `select into`, only one row must be returned. In addition, you have a bunch of typos and syntax errors. Here is some code that doesn't throw an error, although I don't quite understand what the code is trying to do:

```
create table schoolTable (schooldt datetime);

create or replace procedure first_proc(table1 varchar)
returns varchar
language sql 
as 
declare
  val int;
begin
  select max(0) as c_custkey into :val from identifier(:table1);
  if (val = 0) then
    return 'yes';
  else
    return 'NO';
  end if;
end;

call first_proc('SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.CUSTOMER'); -- to test first procedure

create or replace procedure second_proc()
returns varchar
language sql 
as 
declare
  script varchar;
begin
  script := (call first_proc('SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA.TPCH_SF1.CUSTOMER'));
  if (script = 'yes')    -- me referring to the return from the first procedure 
  then 
    insert into schoolTable values (current_timestamp);
  else
    return ('message');
  end if;
end;

call second_proc();

select * from schoolTable; -- to check if the record was inserted
```